# How to pass parameters in URL with ChromeCast?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, chromecast

Is there any example to show how to pass parameters in URL from the sender app to the receiver app?

I would like to pass some parameters and with the help of theese parameters the receiver app creates the manifest url and the authorization xml, which I need to play PlayReady videos.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass parameters to your receiver, you need to either use a customData field that is available on a number of apis (it is a JSON object that you can pass) or you can create a custom namespace and send your data to the receiver. the former is useful when the data that you need to send can happen at the same time that you are calling those apis such as load, play, pause, etc. The latter is useful when such alignment cannot happen and needs to be an out-of-band communication.